# Return EntityReference from partylist in CRM 2015 custom step

Tags: c#, workflow, dynamics-crm, crm

The problem is that I want to create a custom step that I will use in a workflow,
This step returns a list of entity references but with multiple types (user or equipment) to send an email to this list.

I tried to return the mails from step as a list of strings or list of entity references with no hope.

also i tried to return each one in an entity reference but I found that i cannot expect the Reference Target (user or equipment).

How can I return a collection to use in the sen mail step in the workflow ??
and if I return a party list as a Entity Reference Reference Target what will be???